# How to address the following error on a Django Project: "django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: Group matching query does not exist."

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to run migrations on my django project and I'm getting this really bizarre error that I haven't been able to address for a while now, and I don't understand it.

here's the error I'm getting:

```
Anaconda3\envs\mbt\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 415, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: Group matching query does not exist.
```

I've tried to run `python manage.py makemigrations`
`python manage.py migrate auth`
`python manage.py migrate my_app_name`

I've also inserted the group names directly into my postgresql database just in case they're not posting. This error is preventing me from running the server locally.

I thought that the Group model was generated automatically and there wasn't much I needed to do to get started using it. It's definitely visible in my database.

**any help would be greatly appreciated! thank you!!**

**here's the full traceback:**

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\nance\repo\project\app1\urls.py", line 28, in <module>
    + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\nance\repo\project\app1\urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app1 import views
  File "C:\Users\nance\repo\project\app1\views.py", line 188, in <module>
    class AllMentorsView(TemplateView):
  File "C:\Users\nance\repo\project\app1\views.py", line 192, in AllMentorsView
    mentor_group = Group.objects.get(name="Mentor")
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nance\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 417, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: Group matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: Just edited! :) If you have any ideas, I'd be super grateful. Thank you! @IainShelvington

Comment: In `AllMentorsView` you are performing a database query: `mentor_group = Group.objects.get(name="Mentor")`. You should not be performing any database queries in your class definitions, it will almost always mess up migrations

Comment: Thank you @IainShelvington. If the views.py file classes shouldn't have a query, where do you recommend that I place that query? Thank you again

Comment: It’s hard to tell without seeing your view. Can you add it to your question?